# Unable to surf to Internet Explorer 8 Trusted sites

Tags: internet-explorer-8, quickbooks

After an install of QuickBooks 2009 Pro (QB) I'm getting a prompt that IE 8 seucurity settings need to be changed. When I click "Fix errors" it opens the standard IE 8 add site to Trusted site dialog.

The first add was fine, but the second one that QB is trying to add is:

> intu-help-qb2://

IE 8 will not accept this value. I need the correct value.

My sense is it's a supposed to be a path to local help files, but it keeps wanting to add this string that won't add.

Information:

- Windows Server 2008
- QuickBooks 2009 Pro
- QB was never installed before on this machine

Comment: This actually bypasses the whole IE Enhanced system and does not directly address what Quickbooks is requesting access to. The series of scripting and IE permissions that Quickbooks uses can be found here: https://quickbooks.intuit.com/community/Help-Articles/Configure-Internet-Explorer-to-work-with-QuickBooks-Payments-and/m-p/201611 and in addition to the instructions there I had to add "about:internet" to the trusted sites as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think IE ESC is enabled. To disable:

1. Start -> Server Manager
2. Select "Server Manager" in the left pane (tree)
3. Under unit, "Security Information", in that box, click "Configure IE ESC"
4. Select "Off" for both Users and Administrators
5. Click ok!

Answer (score 0):

Is IE8 Ehanced Security Configuration enabled?  This is usually on by default on a Windows 2003/2008 server.  If you disable this, I bet this will work for you.